# Exit my program after finding an error

Tags: java, exit, exit-code

My program suppose to exit after any error occur! 
It gets 3 command line and validate and check if they are in range. if they are not, then must  print the error and exit the program!

I did this with `System.exit();`
However, if the program get 2 bad entries it only print the first error and jump out of the program!

is there any other ways that I can jump out of my program after showing all errors?

here is my code:

Comment: you are calling System.exit(1) from many places. instead of doing this set a flag to indicate an error, then check the flag after you do 3 command line things.

Answer (score 0):

could you just not add the error messages to a String array and print the array then at the end of the program before exiting

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all System.exit() and create a flag String[] with message error, and add print the String[] to show errors.